# Is there a plugin for routing IOS push notifications to PWA push notification or local messages in ManifoldJs?

Tags: ios, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, manifoldjs

I'm looking into wrapping a PWA for IOS using ManifoldJS primary to get remote push notifications.  However I don't see any documentation on how to address this in a generic way.  I was hoping for some plugin that would display the push notification, potentially bring the app up if clicked on, and transmit events/payload into the service worker or main thread (perhaps through postMessage).  Do you have to write native code to handle even basic push notifications?  How have you addressed this?